# Correct check for any admin page with editor

Tags: plugin-development, admin, css, scripts

I have read the codex, but found it a bit incomplete. I like to load stuff only on pages where the post editor is visible. This should include custom post types and everything.

I am a bit insure about the `get_current_screen()` Object. When to use `base`, `parent_base` ...

Would this be the right check? Tested it on pages and posts and seem to be working. Just asking because I am curious if I could to this better.

```
$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( 'post' == $screen->base || 'page' == $screen->base ) {
// Load stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the global variable `$pagenow`, and use `post_type_supports()` to find post types with an editor:

```
function has_post_editor() 
{    
    global $pagenow;

    if ( empty ( $pagenow ) )
        return FALSE;

    if ( ! in_array( $pagenow, array ( 'post-new.php', 'post.php' ) ) )
        return FALSE;

    return post_type_supports( get_current_screen()->post_type, 'editor' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no equivalent for doing this $pagenow thing with the screen object I guess?

Comment: @redanimalwar Nothing really unique. But I might be wrong.